# 3D plot of temperature distribution

Tags: matlab

I have a T matrix of 7x5x4 that I got from a script that I run. My ultimate goal is to plot a 3D plot that shows the temperatures in all sides of the cube, and if I can I want to get a view of the internal temperatures as well. However, for now I will be happy if I can get the temperature distribution view on any plane (lets say on the plane (i,j,1)). I am running the below code but I get the error:

Data dimensions must agree

Please help me with this issue

```
DX=0.1; % step size
DY=0.1;
DZ=0.1;
Lx= 0.6; %length along x-axis in m
Ly=0.4;   %length along y-axis
Lz=0.3;   %length along z-axis
X=0:DX:Lx;
Y=0:DY:Ly;
Z=0:DZ:Lz;
[xx,yy,zz]=meshgrid(X,Y,Z);
figure
surf(xx,yy,T(:,:,1));
```

Comment: Is x==X? Are you sure xx and yy are 3-dimensional?  T has a size of 7x5 and xx and yy the size of 5x7, that might be your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code as given (except `x`->`X`, `y`->`Y` and `z`->`Z` in the `meshgrid` call), your three inputs to `surf` have sizes 5x7x4, 5x7x4, and 7x5. These three inputs must have the same sizes, and be 2-dimensional matrices. The other option is to make the first two arguments be vectors

One solution:

```
[yy,xx,zz]=meshgrid(Y,X,Z);
surf(xx(:,:,1),yy(:,:,1),T(:,:,1));
```

The other solution:

```
surf(Y,X,T(:,:,1));
```

MATLAB is rather confusing in their documentation and parameter order... They tend to index `T(y,x,z)`. So really what you define as `X` is `Y` and vice versa. The x-axis is horizontal, and the second matrix index is horizontal.

Regarding plotting your volume: there are some pretty good tools for this [on the File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=volume+visualization).

Comment: Thank you very much Cris. Your solution worked, but since I could not get a 3D plot (in volumic sense, like (x,y,z,T), then I would rather prefer to plot the temperature plot on any plane I want; let's say on the right side of the cube, the left side, the top...and any planes in between. I really appreciate your work.

Comment: I get it. I just added view(2) command. Thank you for all the help!